# Can i Write a file to a pendrive using stm32f401ccu6?

Tags: usb, stm32, fatfs

I wanna be able to write a file to a pendrive using a MCU, so i tried to use stm32f401ccu6 on a blackpill board that has acess to the USB OTG communication, but there is very few examples and even though i heve read the documentation i didn't get it to work.

I tried to use fatfs and usb_host through STM32CUBEIDE to try to write a file to a pendrive, but i am unable to make **if(FATFS_LinkDriver(&USBH_Driver, USBHPath) == 0)** i would be glad to receive some tips. thanks

Comment: So, what does it return? FATFS_LinkDriver(&USBH_Driver, USBHPath)?